# ¿Cómo modificar los valores de unas variables de un dataframe en R?

Tags: r, dataframe

Tengo un dataframe (`datos_adultos`) y quiero **modificar los valores de algunas de sus variables de igual forma**, dichas variables toman valores entre 0 y 4 y quiero modificarlas de la siguiente manera:

- Cuando los valores de estas variables toman los valores 0 y 1 cambiarlos todas a 0
- Cuando los valores de estas variables toman los valores 2 y 3 cambiarlos todos a 1

Estas variables incluidas en mi dataframe reflejan el estado de salud mental en distintos aspectos: frecuencia con la que se ha podido concetrar(`SM_frec_concentr`), frecuencia con la que se ha sentido agobiado(`SM_frec_agob`), valorado(`SM_frec_vale`),etc. Con ellas pretendo elaborar un índice (GHQ-12) que refleje el estado de salud mental.

Esto es lo que he intentado hacer:

```
# Nombre de las variables que deseo modificar
name_vars_GHQ_12 <- c("SM_frec_concentr","SM_frec_preoc","SM_frec_desemp",
                      "SM_frec_decis","SM_frec_agob","SM_frec_super",
                      "SM_frec_disfr","SM_frec_frente","SM_frec_deprim",
                      "SM_frec_confi","SM_frec_vale","SM_frec_feliz")

# Las agrupo para poder trabajar con ellas
vars_GHQ_12 <- datos_adultos[name_vars_GHQ_12]

# Las modifico tal y como deseo
vars_GHQ_12 == 1 <- 0 # Cuando las variables toman el valor 1 cambiarlas a 0
vars_GHQ_12 == 2 <- 1 # Cuando las variables toman el valor 2 cambiarlas a 1
vars_GHQ_12 == 3 <- 1 # Cuando las variables toman el valor 3 cambiarlas a 1
```

Sin embargo, cuando ejecuto las tres últimas líneas de código me aparece el siguiente error:

> Error in vars_GHQ_12 == 1 <- 0 : could not find function "==<-"
>
> Error in vars_GHQ_12 == 2 <- 1 : could not find function "==<-"
>
> Error in vars_GHQ_12 == 3 <- 1 : could not find function "==<-"

¿Cómo hago entonces para modificar este grupo de variables tal y como deseo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo puedes intentar, es hacer algo así:

```
vars_GHQ_12[, name_vars_GHQ_12] <- as.integer(vars_GHQ_12[, name_vars_GHQ_12] > 1)
```

Detalle:

- Seleccionamos las columnas de interés mediante `vars_GHQ_12[, name_vars_GHQ_12]`
- a las mismas le asignaremos los valores de la comparación `vars_GHQ_12[, name_vars_GHQ_12] > 1` y como queremos un número y no un lógico, lo coercionamos a un entero mediante `as.integer()`

En cuanto a lo que has intentado, si bien es claro que la sintaxis es incorrecta, estas comparando la igualdad de un objeto con el resultado de una asignación no permitida (literal <- literal), es desconcertante el mensaje de error y por ahora no tengo idea de como R interpreta la clausula anterior.